# flask app won't load in browser after executing docker-compose up

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to learn to deploy apps using docker. I have a flask app I am trying to deploy. Each time I run docker-compose up, the output doesn't show any errors but the app won't load in the browser. I make use of flask-sqlalchemy to connect to a mysql database. The contents of my docker-compose file are as follows:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      ports:
         - "32000:3306"
      environment:
         MYSQL_HOST: db
         MYSQL_USER: root
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: data_scientist
      volumes:
          - ./db/route_client.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/route_client.sql:ro

  app:

     build: C:\abdul_files\flask_apps\leaflet\control_search
     links:
       - db
     ports:
       - "5001:5000"
     depends_on:
       - db
```

The contents of my Dockerfile are as follows:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as an image
  FROM python:2.7.9

# The EXPOSE instruction indicates the ports on which a container 
# will listen for connections
# Since Flask apps listen to port 5000  by default, we expose it
  EXPOSE 5000

# Sets the working directory for following COPY and CMD instructions
# Notice we haven’t created a directory by this name - this instruction 
# creates a directory with this name if it doesn’t exist
  WORKDIR /control_search

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
  COPY requirements.txt /control_search
  RUN pip install -r requirements.txt



# Run app.py when the container launches
  COPY . /control_search
  CMD python control_search.py
```

The contents of my config file where I have my sqlalchemy database uri are as follows:

```
import os

class Config(object):
     SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:data_scientist@db/route_client'
     SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
     SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
```

As I said earlier, the docker-compose up command executes without errors but the app won't load in the browser. Any pointers to what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's in `control_search.py` ... you haven't shown your `app.run` statement, which I assume you are using.

Comment: What is the actual error you get?  What does the top level of your application look like (do you explicitly bind to `0.0.0.0`)?  The version of Python you're using is obsolete; can you upgrade to something that's continuing to get updates and bug fixes?

Comment: @v25 ...Sorry I was previously using app.run(threaded=True) but I have changed it to app.run(host=0.0.0.0) but the app still won't run. Using Windows so the Docker Dashboard launches MS Edge broswer by default. When I launch the app I get a "Hmmm...can’t reach this page" message in the browser. Will edit my question to show the output of docker-compose logs -f

Comment: @David Maze ...lol..I am aware this version is obsolete. Due to inexperience and some ignorance I made some poor choices at the start of this project. However, before trying to get the app to run on docker, I had gotten it to run normally on my laptop and on a linode server. The linode version isn't currently running tho.

Comment: Sorry I was tried to post the output of docker-compose logs -f, but I can't get it to be formatted nicely, but it doesn't show any errors.